# utext_openUTF8 return error for string "mod-12k";

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

In following small program I cant figure out why the utext_openUTF8 return with error..

```
  int utf8_is_it_model3(std::string input_string)
  {
int error_number=0;
UText *ut = NULL;
    UErrorCode status;

    //char *pEnd;
const char * c2 = input_string.c_str();
    ut = utext_openUTF8(ut, c2, -1, &status);
 if(U_FAILURE(status))
 {
            error_number=-1
    std::cout<<" Error!\n";
    return error_number;
 }



utext_close(ut);

 return error_number;

 }   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int i;
bool is_it_model=false;
std::string input_string="mod-12k";
//std::string input_string="m54-q";
//std::string input_string="- ";
i=utf8_is_it_model3(input_string);

return 0;
    }
```

output:
 Error!

when I change the std::string input_string="mod-12k"; with the std::string input_string="sko-w";
I have no error...

I am using ubuntu 64 bit 12.04  and c++ and ICU 49

I cant find out what i am doing wrong...

Comment: Print your string content in hex when you output an error. You just might find a surprise.

Comment: std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale());   adding the above line make the bug  solved.

Comment: @user1675224 if that solved it, please add an answer to your own question and mark it solved.

Comment: @user1675224 that's not the problem, see my other answer

Comment: @user1675224 The line you put in shouldn't be necessary and doesn't really fix it.  You're liable to randomly fail unless you initialize the UErrorCode properly.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is you need this on line 5:

`UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;`